# Proving $f$ is Riemann integrable iff for every $\varepsilon >0$ and partitions $P$ and $S, U(f,P) - L(f,S) < \varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

Now I see this question as naturally applying Riemann's condition, which states that $f$ is Riemann integrable iff $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \varepsilon$. I think this kind of automatically solves itself in the forward direction if I am not mistaken.The key question being, can it be any partition? (as in $S$ and $P$ both work, and so can be plugged in at will?)

Conversely, same logic applied in reverse means it's Riemann integrable. I am just unsure, I feel I am skipping steps.

Comment: Well What's **your** definition of Riemann integrable? I my self would use an $\varepsilon$ proof to prove both ways.

Comment: I would typically use Riemann's condition, so also epsilon. But can I do what I am implying? Can it be any partition?

Comment: No it's not any Partition, it's like how for sequences when $\varepsilon$ is set then we can find an $N$... This is the same way, when $\varepsilon$ is set there is a $P$ partition such that for $P$ and any refinement of $P$ we have the Riemann condition.

Comment: The converse is easy. If for every $\varepsilon > 0$ and partitions $P$ and $S$, the condition holds, then in particular, fix some partition $P$ and now $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \varepsilon$, so $f$ is Riemann integrable by defintion.

The forward direction is not so clear. Riemann integrability only implies that for some partition, $U(f,P)-L(f,P) < \varepsilon$; it does not say that this is true for all $P$, and it does not say you can change which partition you use for the upper and lower summations.

Comment: I realize now I worded the questions confusingly. The $S$ and $P$ are also partitions that exist. It cannot be any partition

Comment: Ok to clarify you have two different partitions $S$ and $P$, that "work". and you want to show that $U(f,P)-L(f,S)<\varepsilon$. and visa versa.

Comment: I want to prove that f is Riemann integrable if and only if, for all epsilon, there exists partitions $S$ and $P$ such that $$U(f,P) - L(f,S) < \varepsilon$$

Comment: Ok I get what you're saying now. Forward direction Let $S$ be a refinement of $P$. Then $L(f,S)\ge L(f,P)$, and the rest can be proven. Backwards direction If $U(f,P)-L(f,S)<\varepsilon$ Then what about $T:= P\cup S$, can you show that $U(f,T)-L(f,T)<\varepsilon$?